# express res.send as result of promise

Tags: node.js, express

I'm not understanding what's going on...

Using `q` promises, this works:

```
const deferred = q.defer();
deferred.resolve('Hellow');

const myPromise = deferred.promise;

router.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    myPromise.then((result) => res.send(result));
});
```

but this doesn't, it keeps the browser like if the request never ends:

```
router.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    myPromise.then(res.send);
});
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is the fragment of the `express` library related to `res.send`:

```
res.send = function send(body) {
    var chunk = body;
    var encoding;
    var len;
    var req = this.req;
    var type;

    // settings
    var app = this.app;

    // allow status / body
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        // res.send(body, status) backwards compat
        if (typeof arguments[0] !== 'number' && typeof arguments[1] === 'number') {
            deprecate('res.send(body, status): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead');
            this.statusCode = arguments[1];
        } else {
            deprecate('res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead');
            this.statusCode = arguments[0];
            chunk = arguments[1];
        }
    }
 //.....
```

As you can see, there are lots of `this` references. In your case `myPromise.then(res.send)` the `this` refers to promise object, not to `res`, that's why your code doesn't work.

You can change the context by using [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method, so `this` will refer to `res` object:

```
router.get('/items', (req, res) => {
    myPromise.then(res.send.bind(res));
});
```

Comment: `.bind-this` evil, thanks, there should be a tag for this :)