# express post make provisionnel headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a response for post request in express, when the response is a simple text:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var httpFind = require('./mongoFind');

var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/url/myUrl',upload.array(),function(req, res){
       var request = req.body;

         switch(request.type){
            case 'add':                                 
                      res.send('Tudo bem!');                
             
                break;
    //...
    }
 });
```

There is no problem in the request in chrome and firefox. But, when i make:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var httpFind = require('./mongoFind');

var upload = multer(); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/url/myUrl',upload.array(),function(req, res){
       var request = req.body;

         switch(request.type){
            case 'add':
                httpFind.mgFind('elements').then(function(result){
                     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
                      res.send(JSON.stringify(result));                     
                 }); 
                break;
    //...
    }
 });
```

chrome shout at me: Provisional headers are shown, and request is canceled.

Comment: Have you tried using `res.json` without first setting the headers?

Comment: res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'});

Comment: Thanks for your answers; 
but with res.json the problem is the same.
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}); 
the server say: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Just one thing: the result of promise is a object's array, and it works with console.log(result).

Comment: here, i think is the same problem, but not work for me :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187342/express-res-send-as-result-of-promise

Comment: @marviodarosafreire make sure you write the headers before sending the response so use `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')` or any other method before actually returning the response with `res.json`.
**EDIT**: about the provisional headers warning do you have any extensions enabled that might cause this such as AdBlocker?

Comment: Thanks @Rewire. Yes setHeader is before res.json. It not work.
I think that my problem is the res.json inside promise.
here is the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187342/express-res-send-as-result-of-promise
But it not work for me... yet. for extension, no, i don't have it, and i think it's not important in my case.

Comment: Effectively, res inside promise it's not the same object as in function(req, res).
I don't know how pointer for the good res!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works.
I capture 'res' before the promise in a variable and use this variable instead of 'res' in promise

```js
var upload = multer(); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.post('/url/myUrl',upload.array(),function(req, res){
       var request = req.body;
    var sendit = res;//voila!

         switch(request.type){
            case 'add':
            httpFind.mgFind('hemers').then(function(result){
                    sendit.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
                      sendit.json(result);                
                }).catch(err => sendit.send('Ops, something has gone wrong'));
                break;
    //...
    }
 });
```